# Trying to get property of non-object in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting a error when executed the function.

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/create_crpo_view.php

Line Number: 35 (1st echo in the view )

Controller

```
function index() {
$data['ds_division'] = $this->mcreate_crpo->get_dsdivision();
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('create_crpo_view', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Model

```
function get_dsdivision() {
    $this->db->select('DSDivisionId');
    $this->db->select('ds_division_name');
    $this->db->from('ds_division');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
    }
```

view

```
<?php
                    foreach ($ds_division as $row) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row->ds_division->DSDivisionId.'">'.$row->ds_division->ds_division_name.'</option>';                            
                    } 
                    echo form_dropdown('select', $ds_division, '', 'class="dropdown_box"');
                    echo form_label('DS division');
                    echo "<div id = \"radio_list\">";

                    ?>
```

Comment: mcreate_crpo is not an object?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an array, not an object.
Try this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['DSDivisionId'].'">';
```

notice that:
`result_array`, returns your query as an Array.
`result`, returns your query as an Object

for more info visit [Generating Query Results](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/results.html) on C.I 2.2 or [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) on C.I 3.0

Comment: can you show your array data using prin_r($ds_division)

Comment: you just have to change the `echo` inside the `foreach` on your view. you actually don't have a `object` so you can't do `$row->DSDivisionId`, you have to do `$row['DSDivisionId']` . 
I can't `print_r($ds_division)` because i don't know where you are getting this from, basicaly i dont know what it is...